# lisp efficient linear algebra library

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, linear-algebra

Does anybody know of an efficient and reliable linear algebra library for lisp? I've been googling a little but wasn't satisfied with what I found. I need to do matrix operations for developing predictive algorithms. I've been using octave/matalab for a while and I'm wondering if giving lisp a shot would be worth it. Do you think lisp is inappropriate for matrix operations? 
Thank you, 
Luca

Comment: Which flavour of lisp? For Common Lisp there is [MatLisp](http://matlisp.sourceforge.net/) for example.

Comment: ANSI Common Lisp. Have you used MatLisp?

Comment: Looks like MatLisp has not been updated in a while.

Comment: For options, you can check the [mathematics node on CLiki](http://www.cliki.net/Mathematics), which has around 15 options (including MatLisp) on linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you Dan, that was the first thing I did before posting, I hope to find someone with experience with one of those libraries. I'm afraid to start using something that might be old or poorly supported and then getting stuck on some kind of bug or weird issue. But I'm definitely going to have another look at them.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at cl-blapack, available from Quicklisp, which has FFI-bindings for the C wrappers of LAPACK and BLAS.